# Doctrine2 - Columns change to null just before flushing

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to insert a new object/row in a database. The object is created like so:

```
$nodeaccess = new Nodeaccess(); // A by doctrine2 generated entity
$nodeaccess->setAccesslevel(0);
$nodeaccess->setDraw(0);
$nodeaccess->setUserid($userid);
$nodeaccess->setNodename($this->getUser()->getUsername() . ' Node');
$nodeaccess->setMac($node);
```

All columns of the table are set. When I print `$nodeaccess->getUserid()` and `$nodeaccess->getMac()` the desired results are printed. And they are **both not null**.

But when the object is persisted like so:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($nodeaccess);
$em->flush();
```

the following error happens:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO nodeaccess (mac,
>   userID, accessLevel, nodeName, draw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with
>   params {"1":null,"2":null,"3":0,"4":"Example Node","5":0}:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'mac'
>   cannot be **null**

The mac and userID combined is the primary key and they are both foreign keys aswell.
They are setup in the model like this:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mac", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $mac;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="userID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 **/
private $userid;
```

Public accessors are implemented and I have tried changing the fields to public but it did not help.

**Update**
The accessors:

```
public function getMac()
{
    return $this->mac;
}

public function setMac($mac)
{
    $this->mac = $mac;
}

public function getUserid()
{
    return $this->userid;
}

public function setUserid($userid)
{
    $this->userid = $userid;
}
```

**Update 2**
I have changed the table, now only the `mac` field is NULL.
The new model:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mac", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 */
private $mac;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="userID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 **/
private $userid;
```

**UPDATE** The controller action:

```
public function inviteAction() {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('GeninnoEDSBundle:Nodeaccess');
    $options = $repository->createQueryBuilder('na')
            .......
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('user', 'text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => '+ Gebruiker'
                )
            ))
            ->add('node', 'hidden')
            ->getForm();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            $user_repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('GeninnoEDSBundle:User');
            $user = $user_repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $data['user']));

            $node_repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('GeninnoEDSBundle:Node');
            $node = $node_repository->find($data['node']);

            $nodeaccess = new Nodeaccess();
            $nodeaccess->setAccesslevel(0);
            $nodeaccess->setDraw(0);
            $nodeaccess->setUserid($user);
            $nodeaccess->setNodename($this->getUser()->getUsername() . ' Node');
            $nodeaccess->setMac($node);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($nodeaccess);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    return array('options' => $options, 'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Comment: Try to make the attributs protected or public and implement accessors.

Comment: Accessors are implemented and changing the fields to public did not help. I will update the question

Comment: @RaymenScholten if you `var_dump` the object before persisting it, do the properties have the specified values?

Comment: Yes they both have the specified values

Comment: Could you please post your setters too?

Comment: @gilden I have updated the question, it now includes the accessors

Comment: @Raymen have you updated your database schema?

Comment: just wonder Why do you have `@ORM\Id` for foreign fields? They should be already defined in their own entities.

Comment: @Tigris I have them as ID because otherwise the table would not have a primary key which is necessary for Doctrine2

Comment: @Tigris I have updated my question with a partial solution. Now the userID is no longer NULL

Comment: And you still cannot set 'mac', it turns out to be NULL right?

Comment: @Tigris That is right. I also just tried adding OneToOne mappings to both the foreign keys. But I get the same error. They both are set just before I flush them. The 'mac' and userID' field have the specified values after persisting them, just not after flushing.

Comment: What are the value of `$node` and `$userid` when you affect then to the `$nodeaccess` properties?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Using the OneToOne mapping and without the mapping, they both are the values I assigned them to

Comment: Can you show us those values?

Comment: Please post your entire controller function.

Comment: @Lighthart Question updated

Comment: @cheesemacfly The values are objects: `die($nodeaccess->getUserid()->getId() . ' - ' . $nodeaccess->getMac()->getMac());` prints `76 - 19917141374`

Comment: I regret to inform you this is a transformer issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed by regenerating this particular entity (oh oh). The fields have changed to:

```
/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userID", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $userid;

/**
 * @var \Node
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Node")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mac", referencedColumnName="mac")
 * })
 */
private $mac;
```

**UPDATE**

That might not have been the fix I thought it was. Had the problem again after adding some fields back to the class. I found out that by removing the following code the user was no longer assigned to null while persisting.

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="accessNodes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userID", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $accessUsers;
```

Comment: Still think you are on transformers, per my answer.

Comment: @RafaelBasso Sorry, I no longer remember why and don't have access to the repository anymore

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:  Your hidden form field for node uses the __toString() value, which is not an id and therefore will not be found by your repository call, and hence is null at persist time.

Long Answer:  Use a transformer:

In your Controller:

```
use GeninnoEDSBundle\Transformer\NodeTransformer;
```

And modify the form builder:

```
$transformer = new NodeTransformer( $em );
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('user', 'text', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => '+ Gebruiker'
            )
        ))
        ->add($builder->create( 'node', 'hidden')
            ->addModelTransformer( $transformer )
        )
        ->getForm();
```

Your transformer ( new file: GeninnoEDSBundle\Transformer\NodeTransformer.php ):

```
<?php

namespace GeninnoEDSBundle\Transformer;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use GeninnoEDSBundle\Entity\Node;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class NodeTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
    * @var ObjectManager
    */
    private $em;

    //  If selector is multiple (Many2One or Many2Many)

    private $multi;

    /**
    * @param ObjectManager $em
    */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $em, $multi=false)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->multi=$multi;
    }

    /**
    * Transforms an object (node) to a string (id).
    *
    * @param  Issue|null $node
    * @return string
    */
    public function transform($node)
    {
        if (null === $node) {return "";}
        if (is_object($node) && method_exists($node, "toArray")){
            $node=$node->map(function ($ob){return $ob->getId();});
            return implode(",",$node->toArray());
        }

        if ('array' == gettype($node)) {
            return implode(','
                          , array_map(function($element){
                                          return $element->getId();
                                      }
                                      ,$node));
        }
// var_dump($node);
        return $node->getId();
    }

    /**
    * Transforms a string (id) to an object (node).
    *
    * @param  string $id
    * @return Issue|null
    * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (node) is not found.
    */
    public function reverseTransform($id)
    {

        if (!$id) {
            if($this->multi) {return array();}
            return null;
        }

        if (strpos($id,',') !== false) {
            $id=explode(',',$id);
        }

        $qb=$this->em
        ->getRepository('GeninnoEDSBundle:Node')
        ->createQueryBuilder('r');
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('r.id', $id));
        if (is_array($id) || $this->multi){
            $node=$qb->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        } else {
            $node=$qb->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult();
        }

        if (null === $node) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'An node with id "%s" does not exist!',
                $id
                ));
        }

        return $node;
    }
}
```

Please note: I've added my transformer, but you may need to fiddle with the logic for your application.

More on transformers: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html