# Symfony2, doctrine ManyToOne relationships error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to build a log of some action performed on some site using Symfony2 and Doctrine. I have 2 tables Sites and Logs. The Logs table will contain a siteid which is a foreign key to the id column of sites table. The Logs table can have multiple logs for same site.

When I try to insert an entry in the log table I get siteid is null error.

Here is my code:

Sites Entity:

```
<?php

namespace A\SHB\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Sites
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="A\SHB\Entity\SitesRepository")
 */
class Sites
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $siteLog
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Logs", mappedBy="log", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"siteid" = "ASC"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="log_id", referencedColumnName="siteid")
     * })
     */
    private $siteLog;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->siteLog = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add siteLog
     *
     * @param \A\SHB\Entity\SiteLog $siteLog
     * @return Sites
     */
    public function addSiteLog(\A\SHB\Entity\SiteLog $siteLog)
    {
        $this->siteLog[] = $siteLog;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove siteLog
     *
     * @param \A\SHB\Entity\SiteLog $siteLog
     */
    public function removeSiteLog(\A\SHB\Entity\SiteLog $siteLog)
    {
        $this->siteLog->removeElement($siteLog);
    }

    /**
     * Get siteLog
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSiteLog()
    {
        return $this->siteLog;
    }
}
```

Logs Entity:

```
<?php

namespace A\SHB\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Logs
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="A\SHB\Entity\LogsRepository")
 */
class Logs
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="siteid", type="integer")
     */
    private $siteid;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateline", type="integer")
     */
    private $dateline;

    /**
     * @var Log
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sites")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $log;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set siteid
     *
     * @param integer $siteid
     * @return Logs
     */
    public function setSiteid($siteid)
    {
        $this->siteid = $siteid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get siteid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getSiteid()
    {
        return $this->siteid;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateline
     *
     * @param integer $dateline
     * @return Logs
     */
    public function setDateline($dateline)
    {
        $this->dateline = $dateline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateline
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDateline()
    {
        return $this->dateline;
    }

    /**
     * Set log
     *
     * @param \A\SHB\Entity\Log $log
     * @return Logs
     */
    public function setLog(\A\SHB\Entity\Log $log = null)
    {
        $this->log = $log;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get log
     *
     * @return \A\SHB\Entity\Log 
     */
    public function getLog()
    {
        return $this->log;
    }
}
```

Controller  :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $sites = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ASHB:Sites')->findAll();

    foreach ($sites as $site)
    {
        $host = $site->getForum();
        // Do something ....

        $log = new Logs();
        $log->setSiteid($site->getId());
        $log->setDateline($temp['dateline']);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($log);
        $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->render('ASHB:Default:index.html.twig', array('sites' => $output, 'counters' => $counters));
}
```

Now when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'siteid' cannot be null"
```

If I var_dump `$log`, before `$em->persist($log);`, the siteid is there. I am not sure what is wrong and why the siteid is getting set to null.

**Update 1:** 
I tried to make the following changes and still get the same error:

```
/**
 * @var Log
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sites", inversedBy="siteLog")
 */
private $log;
```

Comment: Same kind of problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100623/doctrine2-columns-change-to-null-just-before-flushing

Comment: ypu dont need to explictly define siteid in logs are Joins with doctrine will do that by themselves

Answer (score 0):

OneToMany doesn't need a JoinColumn. So it should look like, according to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations).

```
class Sites
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Logs", mappedBy="log")
     */
    private $site_log;
}

class Logs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sites", inversedBy="site_log")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $log;
}
```

orderBy and cascade were ignored for simplicity.

Comment: I did that and still getting the same error. See the my update, in the question.

Comment: Sorry, referenced false Annotation. I edited the answer with an example according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

you have problem in your sturcture,

Remove this from Logs Entity

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="siteid", type="integer")
 */
private $siteid;
```

And then replace this part

```
  /**
 * @var Log
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sites")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $log;
```

with

```
  /**
 * @var Log
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sites" inversedBy="logs")
 */
private $site;
```

And in your sites entity replace this with

```
 /**
 * @var ArrayCollection $siteLog
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Logs", mappedBy="logs", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"siteid" = "ASC"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="log_id", referencedColumnName="siteid")
 * })
 */
private $logs;
```

with

```
 /**
 * @var ArrayCollection $siteLog
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Logs", mappedBy="site", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"siteid" = "ASC"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="log_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $logs;
```

And then use proper setters and getters for these new feilds mean pass object to setter functions, for the class they are being mapped for(if you dont know this part write in comment i will do it as well)